# How to display more than one $mdToast on the screen

Tags: angular-material

How to display more than one $mdToast on the screen at the same time.
I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29196794/angular-material-how-to-display-one-toast-after-another-one-is-displayed-while) , but It doesn't suit me.
For example if you try to run this couple of times on click event, next one will hide previous toast:

```
$mdToast.show(
      $mdToast.simple()
        .content('Simple Toast!')
        .hideDelay(15000)
    );
```

Comment: Show some  of your attempts reach the solution, a,long with some piece of code. This would  be helpful for  giving an appropriate answer..

Answer (score 2):

Toasts are per design specs limited to one. I found some links, if it be interesting for you:

[angular_material_issues](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/2799)

[material_snackbars](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/snackbars-toasts.html#snackbars-toasts-usage)

You can add toasts to the global queue.

Comment: The only truly useful part of this answer is the reference to the global queue. Can you add information about that?

Answer (score -4):

```js
var toast1 = $mdToast.simple() .textContent('toast1 ').action('action1');
var toast1 = $mdToast.simple() .textContent('toast1 ').action('action1');
$mdToast.show(toast1);
$mdToast.show(toast1);
```

Comment: Did you mean to create `toast2` in the second variable? A little explanation would help make your answer more useful to the community.